# Display only line intersections of graticule

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to only display the line intersections within graticule and not the whole lines within a D3 map.

Is there any support to do that with `d3.geo.graticule`?

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: no, there is no way to only render the intersections with `d3.geo.graticule`.

But the desired result could be achieved with little effort by putting the intersections you want to be drawn into a helper array which is passed to a path generator for rendering. I forked one of my [Plunks](http://plnkr.co/edit/vYXVx3zfDYDrIkSw5CRO?p=preview) to demonstrate the solution:

1. Set up a helper array containing geometry objects to be passed to the [path generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#_path).

   ```
   // Generate two-dimensional array containing the coordinates of all
   // intersections we are interested in.
   var lonLatIntersections = d3.range(-180, 180, 10).map(function(lat) {
       return d3.range(0, 360, 10).map(function(lon) {
         // Return geometry objects that can be handled by the path generator.
         return {type: "Point", coordinates: [lon,lat]};
       });
   });
   ```
2. Use a nested selection to bind the two-dimensional (lat/lon) array and use the enter selections to append the intersection points. The actual drawing is done by supplying the geometry objects to the path generator which will take into account the projection.

   ```
   // Do a nested selection to bind the two-dimensional data.
   map.selectAll("g.lat")
       .data(lonLatIntersections)
     .enter().append("g")                  // Create groups per latitude.
       .classed("lat", true)
       .selectAll("circle")
         .data(function(d) { return d; })  // Data binding for longitudes
       .enter().append("path")
         .attr({
           "d": path,                      // Use the path generator to draw points
           "class": "confluence"
         });
   ```